# How to configure Glib on Microsoft Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, glib

i'm trying to port to Windows a C project wrote to work on Linux. It's a simple project that depends CUDA and Glib librarys.

I believe the best way is to compile with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, but i don't have idea how to link Glib to this project. CUDA code is going well, but every call to Glib methods generate a "unresolved external symbol" error.

Comment: I'm not used to vs, but I guess you have all the glib dlls (version compiled for msvc++) and lib files ?

Comment: I just have the Glib binaries for Windows. http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win64/glib/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i just solved my problem using this guide to configure GTK on Visual Studio 2008:
http://www.etechplanet.com/blog/visual-studio-2008-configuration-for-gtk2b-gui-development.aspx

The only change i done was about the Tools/Options/VC++ Directories because this was deprecated on VS2010. I added the paths directly to the project properties.